# HTC Incredible not showing Ime Options on soft keyboard

Tags: android

I have set the IME options for my `AutoCompleteTextView` object like this:

```
inputSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

and also in another area, at a certain point i set the IME Options to:

```
inputSearch.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

why is it that on the HTC Incredible, there is no action `next` or `go` showing up on my soft keyboard?  it works as expected on the `g1` and `Samsung Galaxy S`

HTC Incredible running Android 2.2
G1 running Android 1.6
Samsung Galaxy S running Android 2.1 update-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all keyboards will have an IME button. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834938/android-softkeyboard-control-on-htc-desire/3835381#3835381) to another recent question on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug in some versions of Android. Try adding `android:inputType="text"`. It worked for me.
See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15106) for more info.

Comment: This helped me sold the problem on the Samsung Keyboards, many thanks!

Comment: android:inputType="textPassword" worked for me