# Android - Capture "Done" and "Enter" key events on soft keyboard

Tags: android, authentication, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyevent

I have a **Login** page in my app where there are elements as listed:

- username (EditText)
- password (EditText)
- Login    (Button)

On pressing `Login`, it will land into the main screen. The intention is to perform that same action when the user hits `Done` at the completion of keying in the password on soft keyboard on `Samsung Galaxy S3`; and `Enter` key of soft keyboard on `HTC One X`.

So,  here is how the EditText of Password field is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_txt"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

In the Activity, whatever I tried is here:

```
EditText mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_txt);
mPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                        Log.e("MyApp", " ------> IN EDITOR ACTION DONE");
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I did try with keeping the imeOptions for the Password field as `actionDone` along with the `flagNoExtractUi` but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this in [reply by Asha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834938/android-softkeyboard-control-on-htc-desire/3835381#3835381) which seems to work fine for Samsung Galaxy S3, S3 Mini, S2, Google Nexus Tab and hopefully for all devices of Samsung. For HTC it worked on HTC Desire X so far I have checked. For HTC One X, this doesn't work. There is this `actionid` for which the value is `5` which captures the `enter` key action of the soft keypad.

Answer (score 2):

HTC for some reason don't support imeOptions, in general not all keyboards support it. See more at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834938/android-softkeyboard-control-on-htc-desire/3835381#3835381). My recommendation is to make your own UI buttons for next/done/etc. functionality.